# Pass variable to a function parameter in php

Tags: php, function

I have the following code where I tried to pass a variable named "$tutorDetailYearOfBirth" into the function.

However, the function keep does not detect the value of $tutorDetailYearOfBirth.

```
function yearDropdown($startYear, $endYear, $id="yearOfBirth", $match=$tutorDetailYearOfBirth)
{ 
    echo "<select id=".$id." name=".$id." class='form-control'>n"; 
    for ($i=$startYear;$i<=$endYear;$i++){
        //echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>n"; 
       echo '<option value="'.$i.'" '.(($i==$match)?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$i.'</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>"; 
}
```

Comment: You can't set the default value of a function argument as a variable, only as a static value

Comment: Quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) - `The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.`

Comment: I'm curious about the use you planned for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variable when defining a default value for a function variable. You need to change it to this:

```
function yearDropdown($startYear, $endYear, $id="yearOfBirth", $match){
   //function code here...
}

yearDropdown($startYear, $endYear, $id, $tutorDetailYearOfBirth);
```

Comment: @MaggsWeb It doesn't matter if I add detail after posting, it doesn't make your answer any less wrong.

Comment: @MaggsWeb what do you mean? There's nothing wrong with editing your question/answer

Comment: I'm failing to see the difference between the two answers,

Comment: @AlanMachado There is no difference - apart from a variable name (which as long as it matches the variable passed to the function, makes no difference at all)

Comment: @AlanMachado they are pretty alike but one just changes the variable name. The answers are off by one minute so maybe they had the same thought process

Comment: @AlanMachado Maggs answer doesn't solve the problem. Setting the variable name in the name of the function to the name of a variable outside of the function does nothing. It won't set the value of the variable inside the function to anything - https://eval.in/439405

Comment: @Styphon Your comment above is not what I proposed.  You seem too concerned with proving that my Answer is incorrect.  You haven't read my answer - which will resolve the OP porblem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a default value in a function declaration as a variable..

Remove `$match =` and update your function to use `$tutorDetailYearOfBirth` and not `$match`

```
function yearDropdown($startYear, $endYear, $id="yearOfBirth", $tutorDetailYearOfBirth){ 
....
```

Comment: How will changing the variable name in the function help? That just breaks his function.

Comment: You missed `$id` is doing the same thing.,

Comment: @AlanMachado `$id` is set to a default value - a string.

Comment: @Styphon  Change the variable name in the function, to the name of the variable being passed in.

Comment: It's obvious that if the variable name changes on the parameter than the variable in the code will change as well

Comment: @MaggsWeb Which is completely pointless. A, he has to change `$match` to `$tutorDetailYearOfBirth` throughout his function and B, the name of the variables **don't** have to match. He just needs to pass the variable in to the function when calling it. Changing the name like you have **does not** solve his problem.